# Float cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

```
    class Bank{
    private float transferFrom;
    private float transferTo;

    public Bank(float transferFrom, float transferTo){
        this.transferFrom = transferFrom;
        this.transferTo = transferTo;
        BankAccount[] a = new BankAccount[4];
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            a[i] = new BankAccount(i);
        }
    }

    public void transfer(float amount){
        if(transferFrom.getBalance() > amount){
            transferFrom.widraw(amount);
            transferTo.deposit(amount);
        }
            throw new RuntimeException("Transfer could not be done.");
    }

}
```

I do not know why I'm getting this error. I'm pretty new at java and everywhere I check the answer is more advanced of what I know. Could you help me? Thank you.

Comment: I think you want to have `transferFrom` and `transferTo` be parameters to the `transfer` method of type `BankAccount`. You cannot call methods on a primitive `float`.

Comment: What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: What is `transferFrom.getBalance()` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

`transferTo` and `transferFrom` are `float` variables. `float` is a [primitive type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), you cannot call methods on primitive types.

Where did you declare `getBalance()`, `widraw()` and `deposit()` methods? You should call them on instances of objects of that type.

This is only a wild guess but they probably are in `BankAccount`? Then you need to call those methods on `BankAccount` object instances i.e.:

```
private BankAccount transferFrom = new BankAccount(10);
private BankAccount transferTo = new BankAccount(10);

public void transfer(float amount){
    if(transferFrom.getBalance() > amount){
        transferFrom.widraw(amount);
        transferTo.deposit(amount);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Transfer could not be done.");
    }
}
```

This is only an example.

@Edit: also be careful, in your `transfer()` method you will always get a `RuntimeException` if you do not put it inside an `else` block. In Java method doesn't automatically return if it encounters and finishes an `if` block. Also please don't just throw `RuntimeExceptions`, create your own, more meaningful, exception.

Answer (score 0):

How did this compile? (Did it compile?)

```
transferFrom.widraw(amount);
transferTo.deposit(amount);
```

`float` is a primitive, and does not contain those methods.